# SQl , multiple questions ( parameters in a join and putting a column into a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to group a table by date (mm/yyyy) and then by invoicetype, I have tried putting in the code below but I keep getting the error 'invalid column date'.

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), case_createddate, 103), 7) AS Date,
       case_invoicetype,
       Sum(case_totalexvat)
FROM   cases AS ca
WHERE  case_primaryCompanyid = 1111
GROUP  BY ca.Date,
          case_invoicetype
```

I tried this:

```
group by YEAR(case_createddate), MONTH(case_createddate)
```

But I get the error:

> case_createddate is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include all non aggregated columns from the select in the group by clause. `ca.Date` is not in the select, I suspect you want this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), case_createddate, 103), 7) AS Date,
       case_invoicetype,
       Sum(case_totalexvat)
FROM   cases AS ca
WHERE  case_primaryCompanyid = 1111
GROUP  BY RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), case_createddate, 103), 7),
          case_invoicetype
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the GROUP BY clause on the whole expression

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), case_createddate, 103), 7) AS Date,
       case_invoicetype,
       Sum(case_totalexvat)
FROM   cases AS ca
WHERE  case_primaryCompanyid = 1111
GROUP  BY RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), case_createddate, 103), 7),
          case_invoicetype
```

Comment: thanks Alexander, that fixed it , just wasnt sure of the syntax